# Unity App iOS work - But then stop on splash screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode6, google-play-services, google-play-games

I using the playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity then build a iOS app in unity (4.5.5) to Xcode (6.01). It's work but the app stopped in splash screen and contains no error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewa5hf0as7na2ev/log_unityios_xcode.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use latest version of Google Play Games and Google+ SDKs. At this moment:

- Games SDK 3.1 -
  https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/GooglePlayGames-iOS-SDK.v3.1.zip
- Google+ SDK 1.7.1 -
  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1.zip

And also the latest Play Games Plugin 0.9.07

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it presents me these errors: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29444733/problem.png

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this. Sounds weird, but you just need to delete GPGSAchOrLbDelegate.h and .m from your project and do a clean rebuild. Discussion here - https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/241

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I'm using a plugin for sqlite database, he has no problem when I try to update, but it crash my application. 
I changed the "Api Compatibility Level " to ".NET 2.0" to ".NET 2.0 Subset" and updated the plugin's settings.
Thank you for all support !